# Getting calculated result from BigQuery immediately after stream inserting data?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore-based app where users can vote on various questions. 
The app is then saving the vote to a firestore collection.

At the same time, we want to display real time (live updating) voting results to the users. These results should be saved in a firestore document that the clients can subscribe to.

These voting results can be based on complex queries that we need to run across all collected votes.

BigQuery seems to be ideal for these queries.

Therefore we want to have trigger to ensure that every time a vote document is created in firestore, it will be stream inserted to BigQuery.

After inserting into BigQuery, we want to run the specific query related to the category of the vote, and save the result into the corresponding voting result document, so the user clients will be updated.

But from what I can read, you cannot count on immediate results from BigQuery after the stream insert is accepted, and it can take several seconds before the row appears in a query.

We can live with that delay, but we need a way to trigger that, after the row is actually inserted into BigQuery, we will run the query and save the result in firestore.

What is the recommended approach for this, and are there any other tools that can help us out?

Comment: Sounds scary - if you get many votes per second, you want to run multiple queries for second. What's the expected qps?

Comment: I already considered adding an expiration field to the firestore document with the vote results, so that it will expire after a number of seconds/minutes and then, when a vote is received, check whether the result document is expired and needs update.

However, when the document is then updated, based on results from a BigQuery request, I want to be sure that the vote that was just inserted to BigQuery (and which triggered this process) is also counted in the newly generated result.

How can I ensure that?

Comment: Consider using Dataflow instead for streaming analytics that can push to Firestore too. Keep a copy of data in BigQuery for any further analytical needs - but automate the continuously running sub-second operations outside of BQ.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? https://cloud.google.com/solutions/big-data/stream-analytics/

Is there any way to achieve what we want with BigQuery, without having a bunch of GCEs running all the time? As I can see, each dataflow job requires an instance running all the time. 

This is a startup with limited funds and in the start/test we don't have that much traffic and don't feel well about paying for a lot of resources that we won't need until later on.

But we still want to build scalable solution that can handle an exploding number of users with minimal adjustments.

Comment: Did you consider to use [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) to get the vote then call a Cloud Function to write/process the data in BigQuery, once you have the new data after applying your query you can write in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions). I found an article that you could use as reference called [Streaming data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery using Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions)